# check html if a specific message appears

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have this Html snippet

```
<div class="noticeBox">
     <div class="error">
          <img alt="Error" height="28" src="docs/pics/icon_error.png" title="Error" width="28"/><div>The password must: <ul><li>not be an old 

password</li></ul></div></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the message "The password must: not be an old password" text from the above Div Tag

My application changes the password but if the user types the same password twice, it goes into an infinite loop and I want to be able to detect if this message appears.

I am using WinForm Browser inside my WPF project and using C# 4.0

Comment: can you confirm whether you're really using html-agility-pack or simply webbrowser control (and html-agility-pack tag just unintentionally added to the question)?

Comment: Using both. Browser control and HtmlAgilityPack. The browser control shows the page and the agilty pack parses it and clicks buttons. Can I use HtmlAgilityPack without a browser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser.DocumentText);
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class, 'noticeBox')]");
```

This code works. Above code had syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='noticeBox'"]//*[@class='error']);

if (n != null && n.InnerText.Equals("The password must: not be an old password"))
{
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: InnerText.Equals will ignore the <ul><li> tags that are within the sentence in question?

Comment: I got an erorr while trying Expression must evaluate to a node-set.